# What are these spirals for?

Tags: mains

A friend of mine made this photo on Mallorca of a overhead power line.

[image: aviation obstruction marker]

In my opinion the spirals are aviation obstruction markers. Any different information?

Comment: I would have thought the trees were enough to put-off any low flying aircraft.

Comment: Another question about mysterious devices on overhead power lines: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253607

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are bird-flight-diverters: -

[image]

Image taken from [Wire Marking Results in a Small but Significant Reduction in Avian Mortality at Power Lines: A BACI Designed Study](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0032569). Other types of bird flight diverters: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Power-line-markers-used-to-reduce-avian-collision-in-a-study-in-central-North-Dakota_fig5_256462812).

Comment: wow, solid research there, Andy!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm a bit of a [twitcher](https://www.birdspot.co.uk/bird-watching-for-beginners/what-is-a-twitcher) so I've heard about these before especially on flight paths heading north from Africa crossing the Mediterranean (hence Majorca is a prime path). You sometimes get them in the UK where o/h wires run close to some nature reserves.

Comment: I'd also be interested if anyone could say what this is (in the picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/osNPz.jpg <-- I'm (badly) guessing it's a moth/insect collector?

Comment: Love how that explanation is basically "twitching, that's like heroin", while, honestly, it's a hobby, and on a scale of hobbies, it's pretty – harmless? I guess? Sure, makes some folks go outside that others might avoid socializing with?

Comment: Do large birds like storks a stopover in Mallorca?

Comment: @Andyaka yep, this looks like a pheromone trap that has a collection bucket underneath, probably to not only get rid, but also quantitatively observe pests. I've seen differently-shaped ones around here (Southwest Germany), let me try to dig up a picture.

Comment: nah sorry, don't have photos from that trip

Comment: @Uwe I think storks are a rarity in Majorca <-- they're not in North Africa either as far as I know.

Comment: They found much more carcasses of large birds with a big wing span than small birds with wing span smaller than conductor distance so I think it is plausible.

Comment: Very close then: avian obstruction markers, not aviation obstruction markers.